# Connecting to existing Mongoose connection through MongoStore - Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, mongoose

I'm trying to store my express-sessions on cloud.mongodb through existing connection with mongoose. The problem is that when i pass `mongoose.connection` as parameter of connection to 
`new MongoStore({mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection})` I get the following Error

```
  const Store = connect.Store || connect.session.Store
                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
```

I've seen for possible solutions but seems like everyone has the same configuration as me and still works. I was wondering if the fact that the connection to the database is slower than having it locally and maybe reaches first to the `new Mongostore()` than establishing a connection.

Here is some of my code for reference.

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0-kdrae.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true});

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(expressSession({
  secret:process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET,
  store: new MongoStore({///Here I get the suggestion from the IDE
    mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection
  }),
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:true,
  secure:true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize(undefined));
app.use(passport.session(undefined));
app.use(flash());
```

I also get a suggestion from the IDE which I highlighted in the code which says:
`Argument type {mongooseConnection} is not assignable to parameter type (options?: session.SessionOptions) => express.RequestHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging more I see that I had forgotten to set express-session on the require like this `var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);`

ref. [Express-session mongodb session not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299155/express-session-mongodb-session-not-persisting)